# Handle JSON in .NET 2.0 not using any 3rd parties

Tags: c#, .net, json

Is there some native way to handle JSON in .NET 2.0? [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20JavaScriptSerializer)
 is available only since .NET 3.5. I am looking for some built-in .NET 2.0 classes which I can use to handle JSON for my desktop application.

Comment: what do you mean by "native"?

Comment: @AZ, I'm guessing by "native," he's asking if .NET 2.0 already contains libraries to handle JSON. Since neither .NET's [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) nor the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) are supported, he'll most likely need a third-party solution.

Comment: @ohavryl, unless you want to write a tool for scratch, there is no "native" support in .NET 2.0. See answers below for simple and widely used alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

In short: No. Unless you write a JSON parser from scratch, there is no native support in .NET 2.0 for JSON serialization/deserialization.

As an alternative, you can use JSON.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/ or http://james.newtonking.com/json)

According to the front page for JSON.NET on it's codeplex page:

> - Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
> - LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
> - High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
> - Write indented, easy to read JSON
> - Convert JSON to and from XML
> - **Supports .NET 2**, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8.

The page also has instructions for applying it to your application via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/).

If your version of Visual Studio is not supported by NuGet, then you can always just [download the binaries](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546) and manually add references to the appropriate dll's from the zip's bin folder (bin\Net20) to your project.

Instructions for manually adding references in Visual Studio can be found here: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Clicking on "Other Versions" under the title will show you links to the instuctions for older versions of Visual Studio.

Once installed, you can find many non-LINQ examples in the JSON.NET documentation. Here's a good place to start: [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: -1: It's a great tool, but the OP asked for "native", meaning no third-party tools.

Comment: +1 from me for a good worked out answer and at least to offset the -1 from John. @John of you think you can do better please post your own "correct" answer.

Comment: @AZ: obviously, the correct answer is "no, there isn't a native way to do it"

Comment: @John Saunders, you're right, short of writing your own tool from scratch, there is no native support in 2.0. Far be it from me to suggest the most widely used JSON library for .NET. I will take the downvote in stride.

Comment: @valverij: like I said, it's a great tool, and if the OP hadn't specified "no tools", then you would have a great answer to the question. Instead, you have a great answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT to please the more literally minded types:

Answer to question: NO.

Suggested alternative solution:
You can use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) . I think there is a version of the library that runs on .NET 2.0

Comment: -1: it's a great tool, but the OP asked for "native", meaning no third-party tools.

Comment: @John - geez, it seems the SO community is indeed full of pedantic elitist brats. You down-vote 2 perfectly good answers (valverij actually put some work into it unlike myself) because you saw a word in the question? There is no clear statement about what "native" means for the OP. It could be native win32 API call for all i care. We saw the question and gave the "best" answer possible in the context. Otherwise if we took that literally as you did the answer would be simple "No" - and that is not that useful, is it?

Comment: The OP says, "I am looking for some built-in .NET 2.0 classes", which is more than one word, and which is pretty clear.

Comment: it did not at first and when we posted our answers. The question has been edited in the meantime

Comment: ok, so, if the question is reopened, your answer will be inappropriate.

Comment: Is it now?.. Still being pedantic I see. The question has been edited and so was my answer. Or are we supposed to just answer questions in the most laconic way without adding any additional and useful info?